# Javascript constructor behaviour

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a question in respect of the js constructor function. I have the following code:

```
    var PersonConstructorFunction = function (firstName, lastname, gender) {
    this.personFirstName = firstName;
    this.personLastName = lastname;
    this.personGender = gender;

    this.personFullName = function () {
        return this.personFirstName + " " + this.personLastName;
    };

    this.personGreeting = function (person) {

            if (this.personGender == "male") {
                return "Hello Mr." + this.personFullName();
            }

            else if (this.personGender == "female") {
                return "Hello Mrs." + this.personFullName();
            }
         else {
            return "Hello There!";
        }
    };
};

var p =  new PersonConstructorFunction("Donald", "Duck", "male");
p2 = new PersonConstructorFunction("Lola", "Bunney", "female");
document.write(p2.personGreeting(p2) + " ");
```

The result is quite obvious - *--Hello Mrs. Lola Bunney--*

The question is:
There are two equivalent objects p and p2 with the same number of properties and methods. I can't understand the following behaviour when I call the personGreeting method of one object and pass the second object as the argument:

```
**document.write(p2.personGreeting(p) + " ");**
```

in this case I get *--Hello Mrs. Lola Bunney--* but what about the p object that is passed as the argument?

personGreeting  gets the person object, determines their gender and bsed on the result shows appropriate greetings.

Resently I learned C# and constructors there works similarly I guess.

Comment: In `personGreeting`, the `this` keyword isn't referring to your `p` object (that's the `person` parameter since you passed `p` as an argument, which you never use in that function).

Comment: The way constructors (and, more generally, objects and inheritance) work in JavaScript is *vastly* different from how those things work in C#.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your `personGreeting` method. You're either going to wind up with it having a useless parameter (`person`) if you use `this`, or you're going to use `person`, in which case it makes no sense as a member method of the object. The only way it would make sense as a member method _with_ a `person` parameter would be if it made use of both the object that contained it and the value that was passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the passed parameter. Since you are utilizing `this` only the variables that are within your constructor are being called.

You ***COULD*** do `person.personFullName();` and that would mean that the parameters member `personFullName()` would be called and not your constructors.